# Help me root my Vivo Y83

Tags: rooting, root-access, 8.1-oreo, magisk, vivo

So i somehow unlocked bootloader of my **Vivo Y83 (vivo1802)**.

but now after flashing magisk patched boot image my phone goes on bootloop.

and after flashing back original boot.img phone comes back up

*need solution on it!*

Comment: 1.patched vbmeta in boot...as there is no separate vbmeta.img in my firmware........2. preserve force encryption!

Comment: I think my issue is completely different as **magiskinit** is not even called by kernel when trying to boot…….I will give Older version a try though and update here!!

Comment: oh I [see](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/6092) it's that sticky issue [#5148](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/5148)

Comment: yes kinda like that...don't know really           .Have really weird firmware possibly hardest to root!....no twrp either.